# Bean Autowiring problem

Tags: multithreading, spring, javabeans, autowired

I am starter in mutithreading. I am trying to index my data into solr.For that I was writing the following code

I am getting null pointer exception in the line highlighted

Comment: I checked solrDoc before adding it into SolrQueue and it was not null but still I was getting null pointer exception

Comment: You'll help yourself if you indent your code in a less crazy fashion, so people can actually read it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

You need to set the path for autowiring package scan and in your case it will be:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="a.b.c" />
```

After it you need to mark the class as candidate for autowiring:

```
@Component("indexTask")
@Scope("prototype")
IndexTask implements Callable<IndexObject>
    {
    //ommited
     }
```

Next you can remove indexTask bean configuration from xml file. your package will be created automatically.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually the problem is because the indextask bean is not autowired properly.

Comment: Yes, and in this answer i'm telling you how to autowire it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Autowiring doesn't happen automatically, you need to configure it. See the Spring [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-annotation-config) for detail, but essentially you need to add

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```